# Создание локального сервера для проверки работы клиента

Tags: java

Пишет что порт не найден

```
try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3345))
{
        System.out.println("Носки");
        Socket client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connecntion accepted.");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("DataOutputStream created");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("DataInputStream created");
}
```

Код ошибки:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at My_dick.TestAsServer.main(TestAsServer.java:20)
```

Comment: Доп. информация будет? Вы уверены, что порт указан правильно/порт открыт и т.п.?

Comment: Порт создан - открыт

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что ваш сервер уже запущен и вы пытаетесь запустить его снова, с тем же номером порта или же этот порт слушает какой-то другой, не ваш, сервер. Запустите в `cmd` команду `netstat -nao | find "LISTENING" | find ":3345"`. Если есть процесс, который слушает этот порт, вы увидите его номер в выводе этой команды, справа от слова `LISTENING`. Затем найдите его в Windows Task Manager.